# Image resources?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resources, c++-cli

I've been struggling for hours trying to figure out how to use resources in C++/CLI. I've messed around with the resource.h/app.rc files along with the managed resx files to no avail.

I just have a couple PNG images that I would like to use with a PictureBox, but I can't seem to figure out how to setup the resources...

Thanks for your help,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- create a windows forms project
- add new resource file (resx) to the project
- open that file, the resource editor appears
- in the top left corner switch to image mode
- at the top click to "Add resources", and add your images
- in your code use it this way:

  ```
  using namespace System::Resources;

  ResourceManager^ rm = gcnew ResourceManager("ImageResources.MyResources", GetType()->Assembly);

  pictureBox1->Image = safe_cast<Image^>(rm->GetObject(L"MyImage");
  ```

Where "ImageResources" is the name of the namespace, the "MyResources"  is the name of the resx file and the "MyImage" is the name of the image inside the resource file.