# Display icon from the local resources in C++CLI

Tags: windows, forms, resources, icons, c++-cli

I want to display one of my icons (.ico files), which are in .resx file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11908780/6544091) way it works with images but I can't figure out how to do it with icons. This way it works to display system icon:

```
    System::Drawing::Icon^ officialicon = gcnew System::Drawing::Icon(SystemIcons::Exclamation, 48,48);
    IconPictureBox->Image = officialicon->ToBitmap();
```

But I can't make it work like this:

```
    ResourceManager^ rm = gcnew ResourceManager("Control_Panel.Resource", GetType()->Assembly);
    System::Drawing::Icon^ officialicon = gcnew System::Drawing::Icon(rm->GetObject(L"MyIcon"), 48,48);
    IconPictureBox->Image = officialicon->ToBitmap();
```

Do I need some kind of cast from `System::Object` to `System::Drawing::Icon`?

Comment: Cast required, use `safe_cast<Icon^>(rm->GetObject("MyIcon")`

Comment: It says `property System::Windows::Forms::Form::Icon is not a type name`

Comment: Well, that's certainly correct.  Spell it out in full to avoid the ambiguity, System::Drawing::Icon^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast it to `System::Drawing::Icon`:
`safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^>`